# SIM800L not registering to network

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm, softwareserial

I am using SIM800L module. I am new to GSM modules. I have searched in many web sites about SIM800L, every where they mentioned baud rate 9600 for `SoftwareSerial` but it is not working at all in my case. So I started a trail and error method to match baud rate. Finally I found that its baud rate is 38400. With baud rate of 9600 for Arduino and 38400 I am able to communicate with SIM800L.

The problem is that I am unable to register to network. `AT+COPS=?` shows all available networks. Using `AT+COPS="value"` I am able to select network. But after that the SIM800L module still blinks every second.

In `loop()` I am continuously reading software serial and it's printing the following:

```
RDY
+CFUN: 1
+CPIN: READY
Call Ready
SMS Ready
RDY
+CFUN: 1
+CPIN: READY
Call Ready
SMS Ready
```

The above data is continuously printing on console.

Comment: Sounds like your power supply is browning out due to overloading. What are you powering it with?

Comment: i am using arduino 5v pin with IC lm317. Output around 4.14 Volts.

Comment: Tried with 3.7v and 2amps battery, facing same problem. Blinking light every second for four to five seconds after that gap of 3 seconds and again starting blinking.

Comment: Experiencing this problem, anyone who knows how it was resolved?

Comment: @Mwangi Gilbert it is because of low current problem, for me solved this problem by parallel connection of more than 2 batteries (it may be of 3.7 to 4.2). Please try this it works.

Comment: The minimum operating voltage 3.4&nbsp;V, but usually this is not enough. I tried a 5&nbsp;V power supply with two serial silicon diodes. (with a voltage drop of approximately 3.5&nbsp;V), but either of them must remove. Start of calling gives a `NO DIALTONE` error message, and the SIM800 reboots.

Comment: Did any of the posted answers solve your issue? If so, please mark it as the accepted answer. If not, then either refine your question or please post your comment above (which appears to contain the solution) as an answer, and then mark it as accepted in 48 hours, in order to remove your question from the unanswered queue. Answers are not allowed in comments, and may be deleted. If your answer is posted as an answer then it becomes searchable and may help others with the same issue.

Comment: If it's still relevant, had the same problem, struggled for days, tried many power Adaptor even 3A/4A range, but finally, I was able to register when I used a 3.7V/1200mAh Li-Po battery with a good charging module.

Answer (score 3):

I am 90% sure it's a power issue. Not sure on what board/module you're using but the SIM800L/SIM900 needs a burst of current of 2 A during 577 µS (See the [manual](http://img.filipeflop.com/files/download/Datasheet_SIM800L.pdf)).

Try using 4700 µF and a 10 µF capacitor in parallel with the module. Powering it with a proper power source instead of the Arduino wouldn't hurt too.

Answer (score 0):

Might be some power issues, but I fixed mine by just trying some AT command

```
AT+CBAND?
```

Then, `AT+CBAND="DCS_MODE"`

That works for me. Give it a try man.